# Javascript countdown depending on the comparsion of two dates

Tags: javascript

I have a button, number and countdown timer.

Whenever I press a button it deducts 1 from the number. What i'm trying to achieve is to run a countdown timer if the current number is lower than initial one, something like restore count down. For example after 2 minutes passes, it will increase the number by one, then reset the countdown to 2 minutes again and the process will repeat until initial and current numbers are the same. The problem is how to make it work as it should, i don't want to reset my countdown time everytime i press the button.

I was trying to record current date and the date whenever it happened to be that initial date and current date were not the same but, I think there should be more simple approach to this.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: can you show code in fiddle?

Comment: at the moment it has the following look https://jsfiddle.net/dzoz9mtn/